# getting strange error while importing pycaret

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, oserror, pycaret

i have installed pycaret in virtual env in jupyter, using pip3 install pycaret.

but when am trying to import it as

```
from pycaret.regression import*
```

or

```
from pycaret import classification
```

am getting this errors

```
OSError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so
  Reason: image not found
```

i have reinstalled the 'lightgbm' incase you think this may cause the error, but this to didn't worked.

as i am stuck in my project any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've had precisely the same error as you for a while now on several projects (macOS). I don't know what this error is either. I do not guarantee to have the best solution, but I can show you the workaround I found to get Pycaret working.

To begin with, I created a [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) environment with Python 3.9, activated it and installed Pycaret with pip.

```
create --name your-env-name python=3.9 
conda activate your-env-name
pip install pycaret
```

At this point, we have the same problem, so I first start by forcing the reinstallation of lightgbm with Conda.

```
conda install lightgbm --force-reinstall
```

Now I have the following new error message :

```
ImportError: Numba needs NumPy 1.21 or less
```

Therefore, I did :

```
pip install numba==0.53 --force-reinstall
```

Last but not least Pycaret is working and you will likely have the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'Simple_Imputer' object has no attribute 'fill_value_categorical'
```

I solved that by doing :

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.23.2 --force-reinstall
```

And voilà! Now it is possible to get the job done (at least on my side and I hope also on yours).